# quantmod - econometrics beginner

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I am using quantmod to donwload financial information.
Everytime I use like:

```
library(quantmod)

XOM <- getSymbols("XOM",
                   src = 'yahoo',
                   from = '2015-01-01',
                   to = '2020-11-18',
                   auto.assign = FALSE)
```

From that I get a xts with XOM informations.
I wanna have a xts with several different tickers, each column of this xts would be the ticker's adjusted price.
How can I do that ?
Should I download the xts for each ticker, then cut the [,6] and merge or is there an easier way ?

My final point is to plot some nice graphs on ggplot simulating different portfolios.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions, but if your list of tickers is not too large you can use the `tidyquant` package to do everything. See example below. And read [this vignette on charting with tidyquant and ggplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ04-charting-with-tidyquant.html)

```
library(tidyquant)

from <- "2015-01-01"
to <- "2018-10-31"
tickers <- c("XOM", "TSLA")
stocks <- tq_get(tickers, get = "stock.prices",  from = from, to = to)

# A tibble: 1,930 x 8
   symbol date        open  high   low close   volume adjusted
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 XOM    2015-01-02  92.2  93.1  91.8  92.8 10220400     70.9
 2 XOM    2015-01-05  92.1  92.4  89.5  90.3 18502400     68.9
 3 XOM    2015-01-06  90.2  91.4  89.0  89.8 16670700     68.6
 4 XOM    2015-01-07  90.7  91.5  90    90.7 13590700     69.3
 5 XOM    2015-01-08  91.2  92.3  91    92.2 15487500     70.4
```

If you get download issues because the list of tickers is too big, use the `BatchGetSymbols` package to download all the data.